# How to sort out this data using multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r

Here is a short sample of data frames:

```html
dat1<-read.table(text="ID1  Score
12  2
10  3
14  4
",h=T)
dat2<-read.table(text="ID2  Value   Time    Age
22  2   12  60
24  4   80  44
14  6   18  45
16  8   88  40
",h=T)
dat3<-read.table(text="ID1  ID2 Class   Color   Status
10  24  M   B   P
14  16  N   P   Q
12  14  N   P   Q
19  16  M   P   Q
",h=T)
```

We have three data frames. The following table is expected. If dat1   and dat2   are seen in dat3   for each row, the data of dat1  and dat2  are entered in the table.

```html
ID1 ID2 Class   Color   Status  Score   Value   Time    Age
10  24  M   B   P   3   4   80  44
14  16  N   P   Q   4   8   88  40
12  14  N   P   Q   2   6   18  45
19  16  M   P   Q   NA  8   88  40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place it in a list and do a join

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
list(dat3, dat2, dat1) %>%
   reduce(left_join)
```

-output

```
  ID1 ID2 Class Color Status Value Time Age Score
1  10  24     M     B      P     4   80  44     3
2  14  16     N     P      Q     8   88  40     4
3  12  14     N     P      Q     6   18  45     2
4  19  16     M     P      Q     8   88  40    NA
```

---

Or use `join_all`

```
plyr::join_all(list(dat3, dat2, dat1))
```